# libxml2 xmlChar * to std::wstring

Tags: c++, string, unicode, libxml2

`libxml2` seems to store all its strings in UTF-8, as `xmlChar *`.

```
/**
 * xmlChar:
 *
 * This is a basic byte in an UTF-8 encoded string.
 * It's unsigned allowing to pinpoint case where char * are assigned
 * to xmlChar * (possibly making serialization back impossible).
 */
typedef unsigned char xmlChar;
```

As `libxml2` is a C library, there's no provided routines to get an `std::wstring` out of an `xmlChar *`. I'm wondering whether the **prudent** way to convert `xmlChar *` to a `std::wstring` in C++11 is to use the [mbstowcs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/mbstowcs/) C function, via something like this (work in progress):

```
std::wstring xmlCharToWideString(const xmlChar *xmlString) {
    if(!xmlString){abort();} //provided string was null
    int charLength = xmlStrlen(xmlString); //excludes null terminator
    wchar_t *wideBuffer = new wchar_t[charLength];
    size_t wcharLength = mbstowcs(wideBuffer, (const char *)xmlString, charLength);
    if(wcharLength == (size_t)(-1)){abort();} //mbstowcs failed
    std::wstring wideString(wideBuffer, wcharLength);
    delete[] wideBuffer;
    return wideString;
}
```

**Edit:** Just an FYI, I'm very aware of what `xmlStrlen` returns; it's the number of `xmlChar` used to store the string; I know it's not the number of *characters* but rather the number of `unsigned char`. It would have been less confusing if I had named it `byteLength`, but I thought it would have been clearer as I have both `charLength` and `wcharLength`. As for the correctness of the code, the wideBuffer will be **larger or equal** to the required size to hold the buffer, always (I believe). As characters that require more space than `wide_t` will be truncated (I think).

Comment: If you want to talk about the most prudent course of action, avoid using `wchar_t` and `wstring` altogether.  They are more harm than good when working with Unicode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`xmlStrlen()` returns the number of UTF-8 encoded codeunits in the `xmlChar*` string.  That is not going to be the same number of `wchar_t` encoded codeunits needed when the data is converted, so do not use `xmlStrlen()` to allocate the size of your `wchar_t` string.  You need to call [`std::mbtowc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/mbtowc) once to get the correct length, then allocate the memory, and call `mbtowc()` again to fill the memory.  You will also have to use [`std::setlocale()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/setlocale) to tell `mbtowc()` to use UTF-8 (messing with the locale may not be a good idea, especially if multiple threads are involved).  For example:

```
std::wstring xmlCharToWideString(const xmlChar *xmlString)
{    
    if (!xmlString) { abort(); } //provided string was null

    std::wstring wideString;

    int charLength = xmlStrlen(xmlString);
    if (charLength > 0)
    {
        char *origLocale = setlocale(LC_CTYPE, NULL);
        setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "en_US.UTF-8");

        size_t wcharLength = mbtowc(NULL, (const char*) xmlString, charLength); //excludes null terminator
        if (wcharLength != (size_t)(-1))
        {
            wideString.resize(wcharLength);
            mbtowc(&wideString[0], (const char*) xmlString, charLength);
        }

        setlocale(LC_CTYPE, origLocale);
        if (wcharLength == (size_t)(-1)) { abort(); } //mbstowcs failed
    }

    return wideString;
}
```

A better option, since you mention C++11, is to use `std::codecvt_utf8` with `std::wstring_convert` instead so you do not have to deal with locales:

```
std::wstring xmlCharToWideString(const xmlChar *xmlString)
{    
    if (!xmlString) { abort(); } //provided string was null
    try
    {
        std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>, wchar_t> conv;
        return conv.from_bytes((const char*)xmlString);
    }
    catch(const std::range_error& e)
    {
        abort(); //wstring_convert failed
    }
}
```

An alternative option is to use an actual Unicode library, such as ICU or ICONV, to handle Unicode conversions.

Comment: `std::codecvt_utf8` with `std::wstring_convert` looks like a very good alternative. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are some problems in this code, besides the fact that you are using `wchar_t` and `std::wstring` which is a bad idea unless you're making calls to the Windows API.

1. `xmlStrlen()` does not do what you think it does.  It counts the number of UTF-8 code units (a.k.a. bytes) in a string.  It does not count the number of characters.  This is all stuff in the [documentation](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xmlstring.html#xmlStrlen).
2. Counting characters will not portably give you the correct size for a `wchar_t` array anyway.  So not only does `xmlStrlen()` not do what you think it does, what you wanted isn't the right thing either.  The problem is that the encoding of `wchar_t` varies from platform to platform, making it 100% useless for portable code.
3. The `mbtowcs()` function is locale-dependent.  It only converts from UTF-8 if the locale is a UTF-8 locale!
4. This code will leak memory if the `std::wstring` constructor throws an exception.

My recommendations:

1. **Use UTF-8 if at all possible.**  The `wchar_t` rabbit hole is a lot of extra work for **no** benefit (except the ability to make Windows API calls).
2. If you need UTF-32, then use `std::u32string`.  Remember that `wstring` has a platform-dependent encoding: it could be a variable-length encoding (Windows) or fixed-length (Linux, OS X).
3. If you absolutely must have `wchar_t`, then chances are good that you are on Windows.  Here is how you do it on Windows:

   ```
   std::wstring utf8_to_wstring(const char *utf8)
   {
       size_t utf8len = std::strlen(utf8);
       int wclen = MultiByteToWideChar(
           CP_UTF8, 0, utf8, utf8len, NULL, 0);
       wchar_t *wc = NULL;
       try {
           wc = new wchar_t[wclen];
           MultiByteToWideChar(
               CP_UTF8, 0, utf8, utf8len, wc, wclen);
           std::wstring wstr(wc, wclen);
           delete[] wc;
           wc = NULL;
           return wstr;
       } catch (std::exception &) {
           if (wc)
               delete[] wc;
       }
   }
   ```
4. If you absolutely must have `wchar_t` and you are not on Windows, use `iconv()` (see `man 3 iconv`, `man 3 iconv_open` and `man 3 iconv_close` for the manual).  You can specify `"WCHAR_T"` as one of the encodings for `iconv()`.

Remember: You probably don't want `wchar_t` or `std::wstring`.  What `wchar_t` does portably isn't useful, and making it useful isn't portable.  C'est la vie.

Answer (score 0):

add

> #include <boost/locale.hpp>

1. convert xmlChar* to string

> std::string strGbk((char*)node);

2. convert string to wstring

> std::string strGbk = "china powerful forever";

```
std::wstring wstr = boost::locale::conv::to_utf<wchar_t>(strGbk, "gbk");
std::cout << strGbk << std::endl;
std::wcout << wstr. << std::endl;
```

3. it works for me,good lucks.